# Where in my work is my math falling apart when solving for the partial derivative of Residual sum of squares (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, multivalued-functions

I am given the following equation:
$$RSS(B, \alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_{i} - B^{T}x_{i} - \alpha)^{2} $$

My steps are as follows. I provided the images to my work at the bottom and this is just a description of my thought process.

1. I define $\lambda_{i} =  y_{i} - B^{T}x_{i} - \alpha$
2. I then notice that $\lambda^{T}\lambda = \lambda_{1}^{2} + \lambda_{2}^{2} + \ldots + \lambda_{n}^{2}$
3. Since I defined earlier that $\lambda_{i} =  y_{i} - B^{T}x_{i} - \alpha$, I can substitute that back in and I am now able to represent the original summation.
4. I then look at the vector $\lambda$ and I notice that each individual element is:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}y_{1} - B^{T}x_{2} - \alpha \\ y_{2} - B^{T}x_{2} - \alpha \\ \vdots \\ y_{n} - B^{T}x_{n} - \alpha\end{bmatrix}$$
   and that can be broken down into 3 different column vectors $Y, B^{T}X,\overline{\alpha}$
5. So $\lambda = Y - B^{T}X - \overline{\alpha}$ and I get that:
   $$RSS(B, \alpha) = (Y - B^{T}X - \overline{\alpha})^{T}(Y - B^{T}X - \overline{\alpha})$$
6. After distributing the transpose and multiplying everything out, once I take the partial derivative with respect to $B$ and $\alpha$ I get the following two equations.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial B} = X^{T}Y - X^{T}XB - X^{T}\overline{\alpha}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} = Y - B^{T}X - \overline{\alpha}$$

but after solving for $B$ and $\alpha$ I get that $0 = 0$ and I am lost on how to continue from there. I know there is something wrong with my math but I am having trouble identifying it. I never learned how to take derivatives of matrices in school so I am basing all my knowledge on http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/sntn/sntn-2017/resources/Matrix_derivatives_cribsheet.pdf

[work part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjmEu.png)

[work part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBb1A.png)

Comment: Here's a thread where I showed what I think is the easiest way to derive the normal equations: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3803396/40119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p{\partial}$
Let's use a naming convention where an uppercase Latin letter denotes a matrix, lowercase Latin a column vector, and lowercase Greek a scalar.

Then define the variables
$$\eqalign{
J &= {\tt11}^T
 &\quad\big({\rm All\,Ones\,Matrix}\big)\\
C &= I-\tfrac 1nJ
 &\quad\big({\rm Centering\,Matrix}\big) \\
M &= X^+C \\
X &= \big[\,x_1\;x_2\;\ldots\;x_n\big]^T \\
b &= B \\
w &= Xb + \alpha{\tt1} - y
 &\quad\big({\rm Residual\,Vector}\big) \\
}$$
where $X^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $X$.

Write the RSS function in terms of these new variables
and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 \rho &= w^Tw \\
d\rho &= 2w^Tdw \\
 &= 2w^T(X\,db + {\tt1}\,d\alpha) \\
}$$
Holding $b$ constant (so that $db=0$)
yields the gradient with respect to $\,\alpha$.
$$\eqalign{
d\rho &= 2w^T{\tt1}\,d\alpha \\
\frac{\p \rho}{\p \alpha}
 &= 2(w^T{\tt1}) = 2({\tt1}^Tw) \\
 &= 2\left({\tt1}^TXb +n\alpha -{\tt1}^Ty\right) \\
}$$
Set this gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $\alpha$.
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= \tfrac 1n\,{\tt1}^T\big(y-Xb\big) \\
\alpha{\tt1} &= \tfrac 1n\,J\big(y-Xb\big) \;=\; (I-C)\,(y-Xb) \\
y-\alpha{\tt1} &= Cy + (I-C)Xb \\
}$$
Similarly, holding $\alpha$ constant yields
the gradient with respect to $b$.
$$\eqalign{
d\rho &= 2w^TX\,db = 2(X^Tw)^Tdb \\
\frac{\p \rho}{\p b}
 &= 2X^Tw = 2\big(X^TXb +\alpha X^T{\tt1} -X^Ty\big) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $b$.
$$\eqalign{
&X^TXb = X^T(y-\alpha{\tt1}) \\
&b = X^+(y-\alpha{\tt1}) \\
&b = X^+\Big(Cy - (C-I)Xb\Big) \\
&\Big(I+X^+(C-I)X\Big)b = X^+Cy \\
&\Big(X^+CX\Big)b = X^+Cy \\
&b = \big(X^+CX\big)^+X^+Cy \\
}$$
The following parameter combinations will be very useful.
$$\eqalign{
Xb &= \big(X^+C\big)^+\big(X^+C\big)y &\doteq\; M^+My \\
\alpha{\tt1} &= (I-C)\,(y-Xb)  &\doteq (I-C)(I-M^+M)y \\
}$$
Substituting the optimal parameter values yields
$$\eqalign{
w &= Xb +\color{red}{\alpha{\tt1}} -y \\
 &= M^+My +\color{red}{(I-C)y +(C-I)M^+My} -y \\
 &= C(M^+M-I)\,y \\
\rho &= w^Tw \\
 &= y^T(M^+M-I)^TC^TC(M^+M-I)\,y \\
 &= y^T\left(I-M^+M\right)C\left(I-M^+M\right)y \\
\\
}$$

---

So that's how you would solve the problem if you treat $\alpha$ as a separate variable. But what most people do instead is use *augmented* variables by prepending ${\tt1}$ to each $x_k$ vector and prepending $\alpha$ to the $b$ vector.

Then the algebra becomes *much* simpler, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X &= \big[\,\hat x_1\;\hat x_2\;\ldots\;\hat x_n\big]^T,\qquad
\hat x_k = \pmatrix{{\tt1}\\x_k},\qquad b = \pmatrix{\alpha\\B} \\
w &= Xb - y \\
\rho &= w^Tw \\
d\rho &= 2(X^Tw)^Tdb \\
\frac{\p \rho}{\p b} &= 2X^T(Xb-y) = 0 \\
b &= X^+y \\
w &= (XX^+-I)y \\
\rho &= y^T(I-XX^+)^T(I-XX^+)y \\
  &= y^T(I-XX^+)y \\
}$$

Comment: Is it possible to find the min of the function? And what is B1 and $\lambda 1$